# Time on Windows servers out and won't stay corrected

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, time, clock-synchronization

I have a bunch of windows servers that are VM's running on a group of hypervisors, all in a domain environment. Its a mix of Server 2012 R2 and Server 2016

For some reason the clock is out by about 7 minutes on most servers.
When I amend the clocks to show the correct time, they simply revert back to the incorrect time on there own, usually within about 30 seconds, so we're back to square one.

Ideally I'd like to sync them all to an internet time server or something and put this whole stupid clock saga to bed.

Any know how to do that?

Comment: There are **MANY** guides on the internet that will demonstrate how to enable NTP on Windows 2012 R2 and Server 2016. Try Google.

Answer (score 2):

1. The PDCe in the domain should be synced to a reliable external time source.
2. All other domain clients should be synced to the domain hierarchy.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/how-the-windows-time-service-works

Comment: Adding to this, you will want to disable Time Sync from the Hyper-Visor to the PDC Emulator (most critical if this is a Hyper-V environment) as the Time would be forced on the DC from the Hypervisor clock.  I have personally seen this result is times being massively off due to a feedback loop between the Hypervisor and the PDC Emu)

Comment: Disabled timesync on the hypervisor and applied the ntp settings, however when i try and resync, It says 'The computer did not resync because no time data was available.', and the time remains out of sync. I had a google and this seems indicative of a problematic group policy, but I dont have a group policy set for anything time related.